# Unable to display all the Person's information

Tags: dspace

I am in the process of uploading my institution's researchers data, as well as their research output, to a new instance of DSpace-CRIS 7. Everything seems to be working as expected, except for my user's information page. When I try to visualize any researcher's data I can only see very basic information:

[Only basic information is shown. No research output can be seen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHIWZ.png)

Their research output has been successfully added and linked to their profile, as you can see in the following image:

[Publications have been added and linked to their respective users.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dZHU.png)

What I am looking for is for my site to display the researcher's information as it is shown on the [DSpace-CRIS demo site](https://dspacecris7.4science.cloud/entities/person/corrado-lombardi/publications). Like this:

[Person information in the demos site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O3Hz.png)

I have been looking into the documentation and I can see that there are two different types of layout: vertical and horizontal. I thought that maybe I was using a different layout and that by changing it I would be able to visualize my data just as in the demo site. Whoever, the file mentioned in the DSpace-CRIS documentation (src/environments/environment.common.ts) does not exist, [not even on their repository](https://github.com/4Science/dspace-angular/tree/dspace-cris-7/src/environments).

[Layouts in documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViYwO.png)

[Location of the environment.common.ts file as shown in the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZNVi.png)

I know that the information is correctly linked. I can successfully export a PDF with all the researcher data (including research output) using the "Item Export Process Launcher".

[Item Export Process Launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4v8H.png)

Anyone has any ideas of what the problem might be? Is the layout stopping me from visualizing this data, or is it a different issue?

I am using "**dspace-cris-2022.02.00**" and "**dspace-angular-dspace-cris-2022.02**".

Thank you!

Comment: Is this directly programming related, or only relevant for programming purposes? I can only see code in one of your pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use cris-configuration tool. The actual source of your layout issue is that, you don't run the command for cris-layout-tool(Check in manual).

Once you run that command and restart everything, you got the result

Comment: Thank you. This was the issue. The instructions can be found on the PDF manual for the dspace-cris-2022.02.00 version, page 121. You need to run the command 

'./dspace cris-layout-tool -f ../etc/conftool/cris-layout-configuration.xls'